# tKinter TreeView does not work with self.after when trying to make a row flash

Tags: python, tkinter

Below is my implementation of a treeview class which allows you to edit a cell upon double click. Upon an edit, I want to change the row edited to flash yellow for a fixed time. Here are my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
import pandas as pd


class EditableTreeView(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, application, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bind('<Double-1>', self.on_double_click)
        self.application = application
        self.edit_stack = []
        self.tag_configure("flash_yellow", background="yellow")

    def on_double_click(self, event):

        region_clicked = self.identify_region(event.x, event.y)
        if region_clicked != "cell":
            return
        column = self.identify_column(event.x)
        selected_iid = self.focus()
        selected_value = self.item(selected_iid)
        self.get_children()
        column_index = int(column[1:]) - 1

        if column == "#0":
            return
        else:
            selected_text = selected_value.get("values")[column_index]

        column_box = self.bbox(selected_iid, column)
        entry_edit = ttk.Entry(self)
        entry_edit.editing_column_index = column_index
        entry_edit.editing_item_iid = selected_iid
        entry_edit.insert(0, selected_text)
        entry_edit.selection_range(0, tk.END)
        entry_edit.focus()
        entry_edit.place(x=column_box[0], y=column_box[1], w=column_box[2], h=column_box[3])

        entry_edit.bind("<FocusOut>", self.on_entry_confirm)
        entry_edit.bind("<Return>", self.on_entry_confirm)
        entry_edit.bind("<Escape>", self.on_escape)

    def flash_yellow(self, iid):
        #self.item(selected_iid, tags=("flash_yellow"))
        self.after(100, self.item(iid, tags=("flash_yellow",)))
        self.after(500, self.item(iid, tags=()))

    @staticmethod
    def on_escape(event):
        event.widget.destroy()

    def on_entry_confirm(self, event):
        new_text = event.widget.get()
        selected_iid = event.widget.editing_item_iid
        column_index = event.widget.editing_column_index
        current_values = self.item(selected_iid).get("values")
        self.edit_stack.append((selected_iid, current_values))

        current_values[column_index] = new_text
        self.item(selected_iid, values=current_values)

        # This adds a new row if last row is non-empty
        if selected_iid == self.get_children()[-1] and current_values != [""] * len(current_values):
            self.insert("", "end", values=("",) * len(current_values))

        self.flash_yellow(selected_iid)
        event.widget.destroy()
```

Note that if I replaced the lines inside the flash yellow function with `self.item(selected_iid, tags=("flash_yellow"))`, this works as expected. I do not quite understand how I am using after wrong. I also tried `self.after(100, lambda: self.item(iid, tags=("flash_yellow",)))`

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve] that includes not only the class, but enough code to instantiate it and populate it with at least one row of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you're using `after` incorrectly. When you do this:

```
self.after(100, self.item(iid, tags=("flash_yellow",)))
```

It has the same effect as if you did this:

```
result = self.item(iid, tags=("flash_yellow",))
self.after(100, result)
```

You can use `lambda` or `functools.partial` to work around this:

```
self.after(100, lambda: self.item(iid, tags=("flash_yellow",)))
```

When I make that change, your code is actually doing what you asked it to do. The problem is that the item remains selected, and the selection color has a higher precedence than the tag color so you don't see the yellow.

You can see this by changing your `flash_yellow` method to clear the selection before flashing the item:

```
def flash_yellow(self, iid):
    self.selection_remove(iid)
    self.after(100, lambda: self.item(iid, tags=("flash_yellow",)))
    self.after(500, lambda: self.item(iid, tags=()))
```

Comment: thanks. I added a deselect all function. However your solution is better.